# Output over tempate (other PDF file)

Tags: xetex, pdf, templates, overset

I have some template in PDF format. Let it be so.
Is it possible to make all output not on blank pages, but on over of this template?[image]

Comment: Sure you can load your pdf as  background picture.

Comment: Have you tried the [eso-pic package](https://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic?lang=en)?